# What is a "LIST" chunk in a RIFF/Wav header?

Tags: wav, riff

I am writing a wav player and I am using this file format specification: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/.

As you can see, it expects:

1. an initial "Riff Chunk" (which tells us whether this is a wav file or some other RIFF file type)
2. followed by a "Format" chunk (which tells us things like the bit rate and number of channels).
3. followed by a "Data" chunk that has all of the audio data in it.

I have an audio file which has a "LIST" chunk between the Format chunk and the Data chunk, which you can see visually when I hex-edit the file:

[image]

**What is this LIST chunk, is it part of some standardized file format, and is there somewhere that has information on parsing it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example chunk contains a `LIST` of `INFO`rmation that includes the creating software (`ISFT`):

> `LIST` chunks of type `INFO` are common in formats that extend RIFF. When a `LIST` chunk carries the list type ID "INFO", the list contains information about the copyright, author, engineer of the file, and other similar text.
> ...
> `ISFT` Name of the software package used to create the file

https://www.recordingblogs.com/wiki/list-chunk-of-a-wave-file

There are other kinds of lists, but list of info is very common. The site above goes into great detail about what to expect, but in brief:

- LIST is a well-defined container type in RIFF based files like WAVE and JPEG.
- Not every file has a LIST container.
- Not every LIST will contain the same kind of information. For example, WAVE may include duration; JPEG dimensions; JPEG and WAVE may both have author.
- DLS type files rely on LIST containers to annotate all the malleable properties of the file: samples, regions, articulations, etc. any of which may be *binary* data.